# Settimeout in animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

How to implement the code below to my animation, my animation is in infinite loop  i want after each animation it will pause for 10 sec then start again, im using animate.css

**note: i pasted the keyframe below**

```
setTimeout(function() {  
  // 1000 == 1 seconds
  // modify dom elements here  
  // your code here
}, 1000);
```

HTML + CSS code of it

```
<h1 class="motext animated fadeInDownBig">THINK QUALITY. THINK LIFELINE.</h1>


 .motext {
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-delay: 19s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     width:90%;
     max-width:1170px;
     margin:auto;
      text-align:right;
     position:relative;
    }

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDownBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px);
    transform: translateY(-2000px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInDownBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-2000px);
    transform: translateY(-2000px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.fadeInDownBig {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDownBig;
  animation-name: fadeInDownBig;
}
```

Comment: Can you include `@keyframes` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 what do you mean? im using animate.css https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

Comment: @guest271314 wait ill add it,

Comment: Have not tried `animate.css` , though requirement should be possible . Should `19s` delay be applied only to first animation cycle ?

Comment: @guest271314 done! :) i want each cycle of animation before repeating it, it will stay to its last position for 10 sec before  the animation begins again,

Comment: You didn't specify animation name in `.motext` and `.animated`

Comment: @HarishKommuri yah buts its working, because im using animate.css i just need to put the clas of it,

Comment: its working i just want it to stay at its last position after each cycle for 10 sec

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried `animate.css` , though should be possible using existing `css`, by adjusting `animation-delay` to `10s` , `animation-direction` to `alternate` , `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards`

```css
.motext {
  animation-name: x;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-delay: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  color: blue;
}
@keyframes x {
  0% {
    color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="motext animated fadeInDownBig">THINK QUALITY. THINK LIFELINE.</h1>
```